# Entity framework tries to add ID explicitly when adding entry

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Normally, when adding an entry with Entity Framework, it knows to ignore the ID column when it is an identity key. However, for some reason, after adding a relationship to my Company class, every time Entity Framework tries to add a new Company entry it tries to add explicitly the ID with a 0 value and fails. Also, whenever I try to add an entry of any class with a relationship to the Company class, it fails with to a constraint violation.

This is the Company class:

```
 public int Id { get; set; }
 [Required]
 public string Nombre { get; set; }
 [ForeignKey("Customer")]
 public int CustomerId { get; set; }
 [ForeignKey("CompanyType")]
 public string CompanyTypeCode{ get; set; }
 /* more properties */

public virtual Parameters Parameters { get; set; }
```

The problem began to occur when I added the Parameters virtual property to the class. This is the Parameters class

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public int CompanyId { get; set; }
/* more stuff */
public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
```

Also, I had to define the relationship with Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().HasRequired(e => e.Parameters).WithRequiredDependent(p => p.Company);
```

This is the command Entity Framework tries to execute. Note that it tries to explicitly add the Id instead of ignoring it:

```
INSERT [dbo].[Company]([Id], [Name], [CustomerId], [Code], [POS], [CompanyCode], [VAT], [Path], [ExpiryDate], [CreatedBy], [CreateDate], [UpdatedBy], [UpdateDate])
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6, NULL, NULL, @7, @8, @9, @10)
-- @0: '0' (Type = Int32)
-- @1: 'asdasd' (Type = String, Size = -1)
-- @2: '9' (Type = Int32)
-- @3: '20222222223' (Type = String, Size = -1)
-- @4: '   1' (Type = String, Size = -1)
-- @5: '1' (Type = String, Size = 128)
-- @6: '4' (Type = Int32)
-- @7: '24' (Type = Int32)
-- @8: '11/4/2017 17:46:22' (Type = DateTime2)
-- @9: '24' (Type = Int32)
-- @10: '11/4/2017 17:46:22' (Type = DateTime2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping ...

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
    .HasRequired(e => e.Parameters)
    .WithRequiredDependent(p => p.Company);
```

... has turned `Company` into a dependent entity, which means that it no longer creates its own primary key, but it waits for `Parameters` to get a primary key and then takes that value for its own primary key (which is a foreign key at the same time).

I think in your case, this mechanism is hampered somewhat by `Parameters.CompanyId` so EF ends up inserting 0 for `Company.Id`. But that doesn't really matter, because you should turn it aroung: `Parameters` should be the dependent entity:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
    .HasRequired(e => e.Parameters)
    .WithRequiredPrincipal(p => p.Company);
```

Now `Parameters` will have a primary key that's also a foreign key (to `Company`), making `Parameters.CompanyId` redundant.

By the way, using plural names for classes is confusing.

Comment: I removed the CompanyId property on Parameters, made the Id both a PK and a ForeignKey and made it a principal, and it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

just because at creation of your table "company" The property of the ID field that is a primary key has not been set as autoincrement. Adding a new value to your table is a violation because the value in the ID field is always 1